# Netlify making an HTTPS request to an HTTP one

Tags: javascript, axios, netlify, openweathermap, netlify-function

In my Netlify function, I have the following API call:

```js
const response = await axios.get('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather');
```

But then I deploy it to the site, in the console the browser says:

> Blocked loading mixed active content

I've done my research, and it seems that this happens when you make an HTTP request over an HTTPS site, but that request says HTTPS explicitly.

Also, when I run the project locally, it works perfectly.

Edit: [Here's the production link](https://friendly-stonebraker-c64334.netlify.app/) and [Here's the repository](https://github.com/sarrietav-dev/weather-app)

Comment: Can you show the **exact** error message - it looks like a firefox message, but firefox will include the URL in the error message - so, I wonder if you're missing something

Comment: @Bravo 
FF: Blocked loading mixed active content “http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=10.385726&lon=-75.4694171&appid=8e711...&units=metric

Brave (Chromium): Mixed Content: The page at 'https://friendly-stonebraker-c64334.netlify.app/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=4.5981&lon=-74.0799&appid=8e711...&units=metric'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Comment: Are you paying for a premium subscription? Everything I've read indicates that encrypted connections are not supported for free plan API keys.

Comment: based don the full error message you pasted ... looks like you're requesting `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?...` - which is not `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?...` - see the difference?

Comment: @jsejcksn No, I'm not paying a subscription. I've tried the free plan and even the HTTP requests turn into HTTPS. Try this: https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=32.22&lon=-100.50&APPID=c6fdcf2d49a0bba3e14f310bd3d5cdc2

Comment: @Bravo It seems that Stack Overflow removes the protocol from the link. The ones that the error message has, are HTTP; but the one I put on the request, in my source code, is HTTPS.

Comment: no, SO doesn't do that - I assume you copy pasted the message as is - what you allegedly put in your request is irrelevant, what is relevant is what the error message says

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this meta tag `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">` With this header set on a domain example.com that wants to migrate from HTTP to HTTPS, non-navigational insecure resource requests are automatically upgraded (first-party as well as third-party requests). Check out [mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/upgrade-insecure-requests)